# How Could We Define Distance Betweem Two Different Graph In case those Two has different Cardinality

Tags: measure-theory, graph-theory

Hi I am trying to find a well accepted method for measuring the difference between two given Graphs.

I've googled a bit but my search result was only confined to the case that the two target graph has same node cardinality.

My special concern is on measurement of distance between two graphs where one is subgraph of the other graph.

Is there any good reference which deals with this case specifically?

Hope I can find one. Otherwise I have yo make it by myself.

Comment: Does computation cost matter to you and what properties do you expect from your distance? Distance between graphs have the [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) problem embedded in them, for which we currently have no efficient algorithm. If that is not a problem, I would try something similar to [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).

Comment: Computation really matters. In GED case, only 100 nodes with 218 edges and 50 nodes with 84 edges look takes for ever to compute using python networkx moduel..

Comment: You need to provide more context, e.g., what kind of properties you expect from your graph distance. For example, you could use $$\operatorname{dist}(G_1, G_2) = \Big| |V(G_1)| - |V(G_2)| \Big|,$$ but I doubt that would be useful (this particular distance would never be zero, because according to your assumption any two input graphs have different cardinality, and so $G_1$ and $G_2$ can never be isomorphic to each other).